# Запуск приложений на Qt 5.0.1 на других компьютерах

Tags: windows, qt, c++

На моем рабочем компьютере стоит Qt 5.0.1 (MinGW сборка), собираю проект, кидаю все нужные либы в папку, запускаю - работает. Убрал из настроек переменных окружения специально, что бы убедиться, что все чисто, все пути связанные с Qt, все равно работает. При запуске же на любом другом компьютере, на котором не стоит Qt SDK, вылетает рантайм эррор, причем на разных разный, где то с указанием пути к запускаемому экзешнику, где то просто с телом ошибки.

MS Visual C++ Redistributable стоят, даже переустанавливал специально вручную - безрезультатно.

В чем может быть проблема? Как это можно исправить? Может ли это быть какой либо косяк самой оффициальной сборки Qt, скачанной с сайта http://qt-project.org/downloads ?

Comment: Сложно что-то сказать не зная ошибки, укажите хотя бы пару если они разные везде.

Comment: на некоторых компах

    Runtime Error!   Program: <D:/path/...>   This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.

на некоторых

    Runtime Error!  This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.

т.е. отличие только в том, что в одной ошибке есть текст с путем к бинарнику, в другой - нет

Comment: может быть нужен runtime от MinGW, а не от студии?

Comment: а где его взять?

Comment: погуглил на эту тему, пишут такие причины

 - использованы различные dll (например, смешаны отладочные и релизные версии)
 -  в приложении происходит исключение (причин на то может быть много, к примеру файл не нашло или нет доступа на запись).

Comment: 1) dll только отладочные стоят
2) файл какой? просто на машине с установленным qt sdk работает же все. Если только dll какую то не находит, но когда он не находил dll, он вроде писал, какую именно. Кстати, такая штука, на windows 7 можно посмотреть подробности об ошибке, это и есть исключение, и рукается на Qt5Core.dll

Comment: тогда [filemon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) в руки и изучать, что и как грузит, и кого не находит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) , спасибо огромное!

Скачал утилиту Process Monitor по ссылке, которую вы дали, запустил свое приложение на компе, на котором оно не работает, потом запустил эту утилиту, сделал фильтр по имени моего приложения, и увидел кучу запросов к различным dll и ресурсам реестра, в итоге нашел один путь с пометкой <PATH NOT FOUND>, и взял с машины с установленным Qt SDK эту папку со всем вложенным содержимым и закинул с полным сохранением имени на машину с проблемой запуска приложения.

Папка эта - c:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32.

Запустил приложение и, о чудо, оно заработало! В итоге методом последовательного исключения удалил все ненужное из этой папки (в ней было вложено8 папок с либами). Оказалась нужной только одна - platforms. потом эту папку просто переместил в папку с моим приложением и все продолжиоло работать. Ну еще удалил из этой папки дебаг версии библиотек (те, что оканчиваются на *d.dll) и все.

Answer (score 0):

`libEGL.dll` должен решить эту проблему. Dependency Walker здесь бесполезен.